# Google Drive watch API: How to set request headers/body of notification

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/watch

Seeing this documentation, I couldn't find any option to set up additional request headers and body to be sent to my webhook endpoint. So I can't set anything like auth tokens to these notifications, right?

Comment: This is done in your code, you send an authorization header with a bearer token.   However if the file is public you may not need to

Comment: @DaImTo Sorry I'm looking for how to set up Google's server to send notifications with specific data which is relevant to my webhooks endpoint, such as auth tokens for my endpoint.

Comment: OAuth 2.0 tokens are basically a user's identity with limited permissions. What do you mean when you say that you want a Google server to send you auth tokens? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Martí The "auth tokens" I'm saying is needed to authorize Google's server to call my endpoinnt. My endpoint is not public and authorization is needed. Google's server is one of my user.

Comment: Ah sorry, I've overlooked the docs, the `token` property should do that.

Comment: But how about other data? How can I add additional data to notifications' request body?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple options:

1. Add the token in the URL
2. Validate with the headers `X-Goog-Channel-Token` (parameter `token`) and/or `X-Goog-Channel-ID` (parameter `id`)

The first one you simply make Google call a URL with the token backed in. The second one you use data that you know to make sure it's Google who's sending the message.

### References

- [Push Notifications (Google Drive v3 reference)](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/push)

Comment: Sounds reasonable, thanks. Are you saying it's not possible to make Google call my endpoint with arbitrary headers such as "Authorization", nor with any request body? Just want to know that.

Comment: How the documentation is worded, I'd say no, you can't. Note that you probably should subscribe from the server itself since you need to re-subscribe when the subscription is about to expire anyways. This means that the server should have the ids of the subscriptions, which should be enough.